# C#: BindingSource CancelEdit for all objects and there child objects from EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, binding, datasource, bindingsource

Let's say i have two objects from EF with INotifyPropertyChanged.

Object1 has many Object2 and the BindingSource1 has many Object1.

If I change some Properties of BindingSource1.Current (Object1) I'm able to restore them by calling BindigSource1.CancelEdit, before the BindingSource1.Current (Object1) has changed.

But if I create a BindingSource2 for the Objects2 in the BindingSource1.Current (Object1) and change Properties in BindingSource2(Object2), I can't restore them by calling BindigSource1.CancelEdit.

In my case I have BindingSource1 bind to DataGridView1 and BindingSource2 to DataGridView2.
Now I want so Retore Object1 and all its Object2 if the user selects an other Object1 in DataGridView1 without clicking Save.

Thanks